# How to cancel the initial link between devices with Google Nearby?

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have been looking into this for a while, and while there are [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001812/google-nearby-messages-cancel-initial-link-between-devices) on here that answer the question to an extent, I have not found something suitable to what I want to do.

I want to able to monitor that two devices are near one another multiple times within a 10 minute span. Nearby Messages has a detection distance setting that works perfectly for this, the setting is called `DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT`.

The problem is that once a connection has been established between two devices, all subsequent communication occurs via the internet, for a period of 10 minutes.

Is there any way to cancel this link? [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001812/google-nearby-messages-cancel-initial-link-between-devices) does mention that one could manually clear data on "Google Play Services" to un-pair devices. Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Alternatively, is there an API that would be able to do what I need?